# CountVectorizer gives empty vocabulary error is document is cardinal number

Tags: scikit-learn

I have encountered a problem in using sklearn CountVectorizer with a document that consists of a word - 'one'. I have worked out that the error occurs when the document consists of only words that are of POS tag CD (cardinal number). Following documents all result in empty vocabulary error:
['one', 'two']
['hundred']

```
ngram_code=1
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english', analyzer='word', lowercase=True,\
token_pattern="[\w']+", ngram_range=(ngram_code, ngram_code))
cv_array = cv.fit_transform(['one', 'two'])
```

get error:
ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words

The following does NOT result in error because (I think) the cardinal number words are mixed with other words:
['one', 'two', 'people']

Interestingly though, in this case, only 'people' is added to the vocabulary, 'one', 'two' are not added:

```
cv_array = cv.fit_transform(['one', 'two', 'people'])
cv.vocabulary_
Out[143]: {'people': 0}
```

As another example of a single word document, ['hello'] works just fine because it is not a cardinal number:

```
cv_array = cv.fit_transform(['hello'])
cv.vocabulary_
Out[147]: {'hello': 0}
```

Since words like 'one', 'two' are not stop words, I would like them to be processed by CountVectorizer. How can I work with these words ?

Addition: I also got the same error for the word 'system'. Why does it error out on this word ?

```
cv_array = cv.fit_transform(['system'])
```

ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They reason you are getting an empty vocabulary is because those words belong to the list of stopwords sklearn uses. You can check the list [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/06bf797c0deabe2a2f166d19abbd0c305da4d123/sklearn/feature_extraction/stop_words.py) or test with:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS

>>> 'one' in ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS 
True

>>> 'two' in ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS 
True

>>> 'system' in ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS 
True
```

If you want to process those words just init your CountVectorizer like this:

```
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words=None, ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It has enlightened me. Of course the CountVectorizer function is going to use the sklearn stop words. I was mistakenly looking at the nltk stop words, which is what I am using for tokenizing separately before calling CountVectorizer. I was doing: 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
'one' in stop_words
Out[7]: False

And that is why I was confused. However, it is interesting that nltk stop_words and sklearn stop_words are different !  Thank you so much.

Comment: glad to help, you really had bad luck that almost all the words you tested were in sklearn's stopword set.